# Perfect 180 turns and aiming

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops

I've noticed when watching some films that some players are able to do instant and perfect 180 degree spins. For example, I come up from behind and start shooting and they instantly spin and are aiming right at me. Is there some kind of a mouse macro that they could be using for this? Is it just a result of the theater rendering the video incorrectly (I doubt this)?

I can't even move that fast without worrying about accuracy. *Maybe* if I turned the mouse sensitivity to max, but then I can't imagine aiming under normal conditions.

On a similar note, I also often see players whose aim seems almost mechanical. Not that I think that they're using an aimbot (they sometimes miss), but when faced with several enemies they aim at one perfectly, shoot a few times then the aim immediately "jolts" to the next enemy. Is this just a lot of practice or are there tricks to being able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beyond setting your mouse sensitivity high, **disabling** the "enhance mouse precision" option on the Windows control panel (you may need to go into the Windows panel, even if your mouse has it's own) can help greatly for shooters.  What it does is essentially reduce the pointer sensitivity the slower you move the mouse, or conversely speed it up the faster the mouse moves.  With that done away with, when you move the mouse an inch in whatever direction at whatever speed, you will always turn the same amount.

[image: Windows 7 mouse control panel]

The downside of this is that unless you have a mouse with high DPI, you may not be able to have both the sensitivity as high as you like *and* have [your cursor move smoothly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895550) (it may skip pixels)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just unchecked that setting and I'm going to give it a shot, along with upping my in-game mouse sensitivity.

Comment: I tested this out last night along with upping the sensitivity. I still don't think I'm used to it yet, but after a couple of games I was getting over 1.0 KDR. I definitely noticed some times when I wasn't able to get an accurate long distance shot in time because of the high sensitivity. My mouse has a button to change sensitivity on the fly, so with that I could usually manage with long distance shots, but it's extra time to click that button. I'm going to stick with it for now though and see how it works once I'm fully used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well practice practice practice for one, second your going to have to set your sensitivity to max. It takes awhile to get used to but once you do your going to be able to whip around quite a bit faster. And third don't always take what you see on YouTube as truth they don't put up video's of them failing miserably.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was actually talking about videos of my own games that I've watched in the CoD:BO Theater. When someone completely crushes me I often watch the game to see what they were doing better than me.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about practice. Find a sensitivity you're comfortable with for all situations since changing sensitivity on the fly will get you killed if you're under fire. Even though my mouse also permits changing the sensitivity on the fly, I never use it. I have one setting I'm most comfortable at (1200dpi) and thats what I stick at. 180 degree turns are easy at that sensitivity, but 360s, not so much.

Also, try fooling around during the pre-match. If you creep up behind someone, try doing a 360 and shooting him. Its very important you build an intrinsic sense of how your mouse's physical movement maps to the cursor's movement. It'll come with practice, and you'll find yourself snapping in on enemies a lot faster.

Finally, if you're taking fire from behind, jump make a 180 and hit he prone button. The second or so it'll take the opponent to readjust his aim on you is often more than enough time for you to get the kill.

Answer (score -1):

Just a whole lot of practice... I recently bought a programable keyboard that did a 180 degree turn but like I feared when getting it, it was tuned for far less superior gamers and my aim reaction time just using a mouse was way faster. I can play max veteran bots on Black Ops 3 and be able to turn and aim as well as they can. Practice is all you need. Don't play scrubs seek a challenge and ye shall overcome.